# How can I transfer a Firebase project (on Blaze plan) to a different account?

Tags: firebase

I've tried adding the other person as an Owner but he can't see Billing details in his Console. How can I transfer the project such that my billing account is not charged anymore?

Comment: I think you should contact firebase directly for this

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for billing related questions.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/